# Better method to calculate half of symmetrical numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, matrix

Each cell of my matrix needs to be a score calculated by an expensive function.  The matrix is symmetrical, this is the best method I could think of to populate each cell.

```
num_cases = len(case_dictionary.keys())  # num_cases = 10
SmallMatrix = np.zeros((num_cases,num_cases))

for CasesX in range(0,num_cases):
    for CasesY in range(CasesX,num_cases):
        SmallMatrix[CasesX,CasesY] = 1
```

returns:

```
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

easy enough...

However, when the Matrix is bigger and the computation is expensive:
Is the nested for loop the most efficient solution?

```
num_cases = len(case_dictionary.keys())  # 100000
BigMatrix = np.zeros((num_cases,num_cases))

for CasesX in range(0,num_cases):
    for CasesY in range(CasesX,num_cases):
        BigMatrix[CasesX,CasesY] = ExpensiveFunction()
```

slow... due to my function, or the loop?

***EDIT***

Continually working with pairwise data so I went back and tried to work with @hpaulj solution.  I'm not knowledgeable enough to understand why testUpper() is faster?

```
def testUpper(func):
    num_cases = 100
    BigMatrix = np.zeros((num_cases,num_cases))

    upper = np.triu_indices_from(BigMatrix)

    BigMatrix[upper] = ExpensiveFunction()
```

benchmarked @unutbu `test` function from below, against the numpy version:

```
In [8]: %timeit test(ExpensiveFunction)
        1 loops, best of 3: 11.1 s per loop

In [9]: %timeit testUpper(ExpensiveFunction)
        1000 loops, best of 3: 2.03 ms per loop
```

Comment: It is hard to say without more details what is making the code slow. Python loops are slow, but it might not be the bottleneck. WIth that saying, what is `slow` for you? miliseconds, seconds, minutes...? How do you evaluate the `ExpensiveFunction()`? Does it have any parameters, or is the same function call for any entry?

Comment: What is your function?

Comment: ExpensiveFunction has 5 parameters (3 are defined outside of the loops 2 are conditional on CasesX and CasesY), it calculates similarity scores by evaluating R code (using the python package rpy2).  Slow, is relative, agreed, the question was more about the efficiency of the nested for loop as the best method to eliminate half of the calculations in a symmetrical matrix.  Didn't know if pandas or numpy had a slick call that handled this for you.

Comment: In NumPy you would try and make ExpensiveFunction vectorized and call it only once. In practice that is normally faster than trying to avoid half the calls by calling the function once per-entry, since iteration and indexing is slow in Python but fast in native code (i.e. vectorized code iterates under the hood). You may be able to vectorize within R.

Comment: Does `ExpensiveFunction(x)` depend solely on the value `x`, or does it also depend on the `[i,j]` coordinates.  Could it, for example be applied to a flattened version of your array?  There are tools for indexing triangular portions of an array.

Comment: Does the docs for np functions like `triu`, `triu_indices` and `triu_indicies_from` help?

Comment: @MrE I will try to vectoize in R, good recommendation, python function calls reduces to n (umber of columns)

Comment: @hpaulj thank you for the reference, I will play with those

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple experiment which shows that the bottle neck is more likely to be `ExpensiveFunction`:

```
import time

def SimpleFunction():
    return 1

def ExpensiveFunction():
    time.sleep(0.001)
    return 1

def test(func):
    num_cases = 100
    BigMatrix = np.zeros((num_cases,num_cases))

    for CasesX in range(0,num_cases):
        for CasesY in range(CasesX,num_cases):
            BigMatrix[CasesX,CasesY] = func()
```

---

```
In [84]: %timeit test(ExpensiveFunction)
1 loops, best of 3: 5.48 s per loop

In [85]: %timeit test(SimpleFunction)
1000 loops, best of 3: 890 µs per loop
```

The two timeit runs are the same except for the function being called. 
When `func` is `SimpleFunction`, populating `BigMatrix` takes less than 1ms.
But when `func` is `ExpensiveFunction`, populating `BigMatrix` takes over 5s.

So the double `for-loop` is probably not the bottle neck; `ExpensiveFunction` is. You can try it with your actual code to make sure. If it does turn out that `ExpensiveFunction` is the bottleneck then you don't need to bother optimizing the double-loop since even if there is a faster way to populate `BigMatrix` -- even if you could cut the time cost to zero -- you would (in the above case) only save at most `890 us` while the overall program would still take over 5 seconds.

Comment: Thanks, this does explain that loops aren't the issue. The function call is the bottle neck, leading me to believe @MrE might have the best solution so far by vectorizing my R code.  I will upvote as soon as I can (n00b, sry)

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest to apply your "expensive" computing on the half of your matrix and than make your numpy array symmetrical  using `symmetrize()` function which should be with a minimum time-cost

```py
def symmetrize(a):
    return a + a.T - numpy.diag(a.diagonal())
```